# In welchem Fall sollte ich deutsche Demonstrativpronomen im Genitiv benutzen?

Tags: demonstrative-pronoun

Ich habe lange Zeit gesucht aber ich kann keine einzige Website, welche dieses Thema erklärt, finden. Könnte jemand für mich bitte in einfacher Sprache erklären in welchem Fall ich Demonstratitvpronomen mit Genitiv benutzen muss?

In case the above didn't make any sense:

I have searched pretty for quite a while but I can't find a single place which explains when to use the German demonstrative pronoun in Gentive case. Could some one explain how to identify a situation where gentive is required?

[Hinweis](https://language-easy.org/german/grammar/pronouns/demonstrative/)

Comment: You don't have to ask questions in both German and English, just ask in the language you're most comfortable with. Answers will usually be given in the language of the question. Given that your reference is in English, I gather that's how you'd prefer to communicate.

Comment: Not what you asked, but my understanding is that the information in the Language Easy page is outdated in that "*jener*" is rarely used in modern German. You can still see it given equal weight with "*dieser*" in textbooks since it went out of fashion relatively recently, but textbooks are often a few generations behind when it comes to the way the language is spoken in everyday conversation.

Comment: I'm trying to get comfortable with the uncomfortable (writing in german), hence I put that. If it looks ok, then I will remove the eng part @RDBury

Comment: Ich finde die Frage sehr abstrakt. Um welches konkrete Problem geht es denn? Könntest du ein Beispiel geben?

Comment: Ich denke, kann ich es nicht besser eklaeren dann ich habe jetzt. Die problem sind wirklich abstract in natur

Comment: Ich habe mir erlaubt, den Titel zu verbessern. Der Zustand, in dem du Genitivpronomina verwendest, ist off-topic. Es ist völlig egal, ob du es betrunken tust, bedachtsam oder belustigt. Vielmehr geht es um die Frage, in welchem Fall sie verwendet werden – und diese Frage stellst du ja auch explizit im Text.

Comment: @mach: Wenn man fragt, in welchem Fall man etwas im Genitiv benutzen soll, kann die Antwort eigentlich nur lauten: Im Genitiv

Answer (score 2):

Demonstrativpronomen stehen immer in dem Fall in dem sich das Wort stünde, welches sie ersetzen. Der notwendige Kasus wird von der Art der Nutzung im Satz bestimmt, ob es Subjekt, Genitiv-, Dativ- oder Akkusativ-Objekt ist, etc. Selbst Besitzanzeigen ("Wessen?" = Whose?) werden nicht immer/mehr mit Genitiv gebildet, sodass Genitiv vergleichsweise selten (aber nicht ungewöhnlich) ist.

Viele Leute reisen.

Als Fortsetzung kommt jeder der folgenden Sätze in Frage:

Nominativ: **Diese** haben viele Motive.

Genitiv: **Deren** Reiseziele sind vielfältig.

Dativ: **Denen** gemeinsam ist häufig Fernweh.

Akkusativ: **Diese** trifft man häufig an Flughäfen.

Comment: Der Kasus wird keineswegs vom Verb bestimmt, sondern von der Art, wie das Nomen, an dessen Stelle das Demonstrativpronomen tritt, verwendet würde: als Subjekt oder als (Nominativ-, Genitiv-, Dativ- oder Akkusativ-) Objekt

Comment: Ja natürlich. "Vom Verb bestimmt" ist so nicht gut ausgedrückt. Worauf ich abhob, ist,dass Genitiv-Objekte von sehr wenigen Verben gefordert werden, aber Akkusativ- oder Dativ-Objekte eher häufig - sodass der Gentiv deshalb selten ist.

Comment: Das Objekt wird gar nicht vom Verb bestimmt. Um Dein eigenes Beispiel zu nehmen: Nominativ: "Diese *haben* viele Motive", Genitiv: "Deren Reiseziele *haben* eines gemeinsam." - Beide Male "haben", dennoch unterschiedliche Objekte.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Die Kasusrektion bestimmt aber nur den Kasus *abhängiger* Objekte. Generell zu sagen, Verben bestimmen den Kasus ist einfach falsch. Ich habe oben mit Nominativ UND Genitiv gezeigt, daß "haben" mit beidem funktioniert was daran liegt, daß es eben *keine* abhängigen Objekte sind. Zur Vollständigkeit hier noch: (Dativ): Mit *diesem* haben wir ..."; (Akkusativ) "*Diesen* haben wir." Also welcher Kasus wird durch "haben" nun gefordert? Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ oder Akkusativ?

Comment: PS: "Mit *diesem*" ist zwar eine Kasusrektion, aber nicht eine des Verbs, sondern eine der Präposition.

Comment: @DavidVogt: zu Genitiv siehe den Kommentar oben: "*Deren* Reiseziele ...". Außerdem habe ich ja nicht zu der Antwort *in dieser Fassung* argumentiert, sindern einer früheren Fassung, die eben faslsch war

Answer (score 1):

Zur Terminologie: Am sinnvollsten ist es, zwischen [**Pronomen**](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/198) und [**Artikelwörtern**](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/32) zu unterscheiden. Pronomen stehen anstelle einer [**Nominalgruppe**](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/170), Artikelwörter sind Teil von Nominalgruppen.

> Bist du ***den** neuen Nachbarn* begegnet? *(Artikelwort)*
>
> Bist du **denen** begegnet? *(Pronomen*)

[**Demonstrativpronomen**](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/52) sind *der, dieser, jener. derselbe* und einige andere. Im Genitiv stehen sie in Kontexten, in denen ein Genitiv gefordert ist: mit bestimmten Verben, Adjektiven, Präpositionen; oder, als **adnominaler Genitiv**, mit Nomen.

> 1. Ach! wie das Herz ihm schlug, wenn er sich **dessen** entsann […] ([1](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/burnett/kaethche/chap012.html))
> 2. Er hatte das Spiel so lange mitgespielt, bis er **desselben** überdrüssig geworden war […] ([2](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/raabe/galeere/swgal006.html))
> 3. So aber gehörte er zur vornehmsten Zunft, zu den Wollenwebern, und innerhalb **dieser** zu einem kleinen vornehmen Kreise […] ([3](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/riehl/kultnov1/chap011.html))
> 4. Die letzte Zuflucht **jener**, die nicht an die Front gehen wollten, war der Garnisonsarrest. ([4](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/hasek/schwejk/chap010.html))

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrative pronouns in genitive case are needed whenever the sentence needs a genitive case at the place where the demonstrative pronoun is used. It's that simple. There's nothing special about demonstrative pronouns in this respect.

Examples:

> Im Februar **dieses Jahres** waren wir im Skiurlaub. *("In February **of this year** we went on a skiing holiday." Genitive is used because the February belongs to "this year".)

> Wegen **jenes Skiurlaubs** habe ich den Löt-Lehrgang verpasst. *("Because **of that skiing holiday** I missed the soldering course.". The preposition "wegen" goes with genitive case.)

> Das Auto **derjenigen Person**, die auf dem Parkplatz des Chefs geparkt hat, wird gerade abgeschleppt. *("The car **of the person** who parked on the boss' spot is being towed right now." Genitive because the car belongs to that person. Demonstrative pronoun isn't really needed here, but it's used because the following Relativsatz refers to that person.)*